# Compile OpenJDK7.All targets success but 'jdk' missed

Tags: java, ubuntu, jvm

I try to compile ***openjdkb147-27-jun*** on ***ubuntu 10.04*** with ***Bootstrap jdk1.6u45***. Finish with this

```
--- Build times -----------
Target all_product_build
Start 2018-08-10 02:01:43
End   2018-08-10 02:03:23
00:00:06 corba
00:01:23 hotspot
00:00:03 jaxp
00:00:05 jaxws
00:00:03 langtools     
00:01:40 TOTAL
--------------------------
```

There is no error. But why miss a target ***'jdk'***? The directory ***./build/j2sdk-image*** is also empty. Can any one help me on this out ?
By the way, I got a warning when I run ***make sanity***

```
You are not building the JDK sources.
This will result in a development-only
build of the JDK , lacking the jdk binaries.
```

Is it related to this warning, how to eliminate it?

Comment: I would download the prebuilt Java 8.  If you really need to build it yourself I would try Java 8 as the build process has improved.

Comment: @PeterLawrey  I am learning the JVM, and the examples on the book are based on Java7.I also compiled Java8 and it has been successful . But its directory structure is very different from Java7.